# Using embedded gemfire locator and server for integration testing

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a application that uses gemfire locator and servers. I would like to write an integration test that could help me start a locator & a server within the JVM and also shut them down when ending the tests. I could not find any single documentation which could help me do this.

I have tried starting a locator and a server when the tests start using `LocatorLauncher` an `ServerLauncher`. It starts the locator but throws an exception stating `IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM.`

I am not very good with gemfire and do not understand what am I missing here, or is it that I am trying in a complete wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to know a bit more about what you're trying to test exactly. We have different levels of testing in the Geode codebase. If you can get away with just a server, I'd suggest using the `ServerStarterRule` in your JUnits. Here is an example of that: https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/f12055ae3ae4b1f4731c0447af0c4cb9abdd4159/geode-core/src/integrationTest/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/AlterRegionCommandIntegrationTest.java

This rule will start up a server as part of the JUnit JVM. This means that you won't be able to use a `ClientCache` at the same time (you cannot have both a `ClientCache` and a `Cache` instance in the same JVM instance).

The next level of test is called `DUnit` testing. This framework allows you to spin up multiple JVMs and form an actual cluster. The best way to use this is with the `ClusterStartupRule` together with the `GfshCommandRule`. An example of this would be: https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/10d89ede6f90f046c15e12e3d16aed259d7044b0/geode-cq/src/distributedTest/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/ListClientCommandDUnitTest.java

Here, various components are being started up including a client VM. The nice thing about using these rules is that they will handle startup and teardown for you in a consistent and safe manner.